# start-all.sh: command not found. How do I fix this?

Tags: hadoop

I tried installing hadoop using this tutorial, [link](https://youtu.be/ZVbEykh87lw?t=3462) (timestamped the video from where problem occurs)

However, after formatting the namenode(hdfs namenode -format) I don't get the "name" folder in /abc.
Also the start-all.sh and other /sbin commands dont work.

P.S I did try installing hadoop as a single node which didnt work so I tried removing it, redoing everything as a double node setup, so i had to reformat the namenode..i dont know if that affected this somehow.

EDIT 1: I fixed the start-all.sh command not working because there was a mistake in .bashrc that i corrected.
However I get these error messages when running start-all.sh or start-dfs.sh etc.

hadoop@linux-virtual-machine:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-linux-virtual-machine.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-linux-virtual-machine.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-linux-virtual-machine.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-linux-virtual-machine.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-linux-virtual-machine.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:a37ThJJRRW+AlDso9xrOCBHzsFCY0/OgYet7WczVbb0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
0.0.0.0: Host key verification failed.

EDIT 2: Fixed the above error my changing the permissions to hadoop folder (in my case both hadoop-2.10.0 and hadoop)
start-all.sh works perfectly but namenode doesnt show up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you setup your `PATH` variable. Or how the scripts are not "working". Did you `chmod +x` them to make them executable? Any logs output that comes from them at all?

The `start-all` script is available in the `sbin` directory of where you downloaded Hadoop, so just `/path/to/sbin/start-all.sh` is all you really need.

Yes, the namenode needs formatted on a fresh cluster. Using the *official Apache Guide* is the most up-to-date source and works fine for most.

Otherwise, I would suggest you learn about Apache Amabri, which can automate your installation. Or just use a Sandbox provided by Cloudera, or use many of the Docker containers that already exist for Hadoop if you don't care about fully "installing" it.

Comment: I fixed everything but now the namenode doesnt show up. IDK what im doing wrong now.